# java testable code involving configuratios

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a plain vanila java app. It involves db access and configuration file from which it reads all configs. I have used factory pattern to instantiate and create all processor classes and util classes. I have db util class which handle all db related functionality. 
I have to pass db table names to dbutil and other configurations to processing classes. I want to know the best design for passing in configurations to various classes of my app. what should be the design strategy for testable code ?

Design strategy - 
1.Read config file in one class and create various config objects - dbconfig object,processing config object.(Use getters or public final fields to access config fields?)
2.pass in constructors the config objects- pass dbconfig to dbutil and processing config to processing util.

Design strategy  2 - 
1.read config file in one class stire in public static fields.
2.pass the config class to each class and each class will get whatever they need from this class's public fields.

Thanks

Comment: There is no good answer to this. Both could be correct, both could be wrong. This is a design, there is always someone to prefer one or another

Comment: As AxelH said, both approaches are OK - choose the one you and your team are comfortable with. Have a look at the usage and life cycle of your config and utils classes. Think about a reload of the configs, too.

Answer (score 0):

When doing UnitTests you test a small part of your code in *isolation*.

In  particular UnitTest never touch external resources like filesystems or databases. Those resources are replaced by test dummies with simple, fast and configurable behavior. (see [Test Driven Development by Kent Beck](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) )

Therefore, when you design you application, follow the rules of [clean code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) and [simple design](https://dzone.com/articles/4-rules-simple-design). Then your question will become obsolete...

Answer (score 0):

I would personally incline towards the first approach, so that you could closely follow the [principle of Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Whatever class needs information from configuration files should ideally not read it on its own (either from a configuration file or from a class that has all the information), but instead being passed on the necessary values from another class that instantiates it. In this way, all these classes that need configuration information will be testable (in isolation), just by providing "test" configuration values in their constructors.

However, a caveat: for this to be feasible, you will probably have to structure your project around Dependency Injection. I can see from what you are mentioning, though, that you are already following this pattern, since your first approach actually sounds like Dependency Injection via constructors.